# laravel - unable to get array of array format using any type of select query

Tags: arrays, laravel

please help me!!

Purpose - check Domain exist or not in given array, without using loop and all in laravel...

I want array format while run select Query. So, I can directly use the array functions. I have tried many ways but still not getting resolved..

My code as below :

```
$validDomains = DB::table('VALID_DOMAINS')->select('DOMAIN')->distinct()->get()->toArray();
 $Domain = 'testify.com';
if (!in_array($Domain, $validDomains)) {
                    echo 'Not in Array' . $Domain;
                } else {
                    echo 'In array :' . $Domain;
                }
```

But i'm getting result in $validDomains  as below and that's why not performing operation without using any loop :
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[DOMAIN] => 0xx0.net
)

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [DOMAIN] => 126.com
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [DOMAIN] => 163.com
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [DOMAIN] => 186design.co.uk
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [DOMAIN] => 1stglobal.com
    )
```

)

Comment: Why not just use SQL to select domain? / if not where('DOMAIN', 'odomain.com'), where('DOMAIN', 'like', '%doman.com%') is also an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just an explanation not a solution**

`toArray()` you are using will convert the whole `collection` to `array` so you will get an array of objects however, to convert inner objects to array you need to map each object to array explicitly like so

```
DB::table('VALID_DOMAINS')->select('DOMAIN')->distinct()->get()->map(function ($object) {
    return (array)$object;
})->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your way with [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck):

```
$validDomains = DB::table('VALID_DOMAINS')->select('DOMAIN')->distinct()->get()->pluck('DOMAIN')->toArray();
```

Right way:

```
$Domain = 'testify.com';
$validDomain = DB::table('VALID_DOMAINS')->select('DOMAIN')->where('DOMAIN', $Domain)->first();

if (!$validDomain)) {
    echo 'Not in Array' . $Domain;
} else {
    echo 'In array :' . $Domain;
}
```